# HTML No Zoom On Mobile

Tags: html, css

On my site [zaxapps](http://zaxapps.com#contact) when you click on any of the inputs or fields it zooms out on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I added this code but it dosent prevent it.
Any ideas?

Comment: `minimum-scale=1.0` might solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is caused by the site thinking the orientation has changed from portrait to landscape due to the keyboard being opened.**

The keyboard covers some of the site, which in takes up screen real estate, which causes enough of a resolution change for it to be detected as landscape mode. If the keyboard is hidden somehow, or a Bluetooth keyboard is connected, the site looks correct. I've attached screenshots to illustrate the issue.

After some searching around, I found [this site](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/). It appears that adding an `orientation` media query may solve this resolution loophole. Here's their example for the iPhone 6 in portrait:

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**Update:** Also check out [this CSS-Tricks page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), they have similar information with more cross-platform examples.

---

With keyboard open:

[image: Site with keyboard open]

With keyboard hidden (I simulated this by connecting a Bluetooth keyboard):

[image: Site with keyboard hidden]